# Java formula for if using

Tags: java, if-statement

I have a code and I know that it isn't right. My task is "print all two-digit numbers which don't have two equal numbers". That means - program need to print numbers like 10, 12, 13 etc. Program didnt need to print 11 because there are 2 equal numbers. Hope that my program at least some is correct. (And sorry for my english).

```
public class k_darbs1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a,b;
        boolean notequal;
        for(a = 10; a < 100; a++)
        {
            notequal = true;
            for(b = 100; b < a; b++)
            {
                if(a != b)
                {
                    notequal = false;
                }
            }
            if(notequal == true)
            {
                System.out.println(a);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just print each num from 10 to 99, which applies the condition (num % 11 != 0).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

so why making things to much complex!?!!?!!!??

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(a = 10; a < 100; a++)
        {
            if(a%11==0){continue;}
            System.out.println(a);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yep.  I just deleted my answer because this is so much better.  May want to edit it to clarify that the printing should be done after the `if` or inside the matching `else`.  Also may want to add a note that this will only work for `10-99`.  It won't catch `111` for example and would prevent a number like `110` from printing.  But this is the best answer.

Comment: because the question was about numbers from 10 to 100 @nhgrif

Answer (score 3):

I think your making this slightly more complicated than it has to be. If `n` is a 2-digit number, then the leading digit is `n/10` ([integer division](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html) by 10) and the trailing digit is `n%10` ([modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) 10). You can just test if those two are unequal and print `n` as appropriate, there's no need for another `for`-loop.

For instance:

```
int n = 42;

System.out.println(n/10);
System.out.println(n%10);
```

```
4
2
```

Comment: Sorry, I need two digit numbers, but I dont neet this which are equal.

Answer (score 1):

Convert it to a string and check the characters.

```
for (int a = 10; a < 100; a++) {
    String value = String.valueOf(a);

    if (value.charAt(0) != value.charAt(1)) {
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: If it aint tested, it is broken :-( I bet this doesnt compile!

Answer (score 0):

You can parse Integer to String. Then compare the numbers with substring. For this process, 
you need to know
`Integer.toString(i);`.
`string.substring();`
methods. This is not a very efficent way but it is a solution.